# Opencart - Include store name in subject when someone uses contact form

Tags: php, opencart

So my problem is that i have multiple opencart stores and it's a mess when the "in-built" contact form is used and the emails in our inbox only shows up with the specific question asked, in the subject field. So I guess you can say it's hard to tell from which store the email is coming.

I have been looking a bit in the controller for contact.php and it looks like this:

```
    $mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));
    $mail->setFrom($this->request->post['email']);
    $mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['name'],ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));
    $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode(sprintf($this->language->get('email_subject'), $this->request->post['name']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    $mail->setText($this->request->post['enquiry']);
    $mail->send();
```

So I need to add something to the setSubject but I really dont know what. Tried to add "config_name" somehow but it just ends up with a blank page after pressing submit on the contact form at the store.

The best thing would be the option to add any text I want in the subject row on all incoming contact emails.

Any help appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please check this extension. maybe helpful for you. http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=23859

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
$mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode(sprintf($this->language->get('email_subject'), $this->request->post['name']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

to

```
$mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode(sprintf($this->language->get('email_subject').': '.$this->config->get('config_name'), $this->request->post['name']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

Comment: You are a rock, thank you! If I want to add text to it (my own) it is more difficult, right?

Comment: If you want to add your own text, then just replace '$this->config->get('config_name')' with that text. Also please accept the answer if it helped you.